# Facebook User Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using JS SDK for facebook login.

bellow is the code for login button:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,pages_messaging,pages_show_list,pages_manage_metadata" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

This is the link it opens(I have removed sensitive data):

[https://www.facebook.com/v10.0/plugins/login_button.php?app_id={myapp-id}&channel=https://staticxx.facebook.com/x/connect/xd_arbiter/?version=46#cb=f2155df599c8f2&domain={my-domain}&origin={my-origin}&relation=parent.parent&container_width=0&locale=en_US&login_text=&scope=public_profile,email,pages_messaging,pages_show_list,pages_manage_metadata&sdk=joey](https://www.facebook.com/v10.0/plugins/login_button.php?app_id=%7Bmyapp-id%7D&channel=https://staticxx.facebook.com/x/connect/xd_arbiter/?version=46#cb=f2155df599c8f2&domain=%7Bmy-domain%7D&origin=%7Bmy-origin%7D&relation=parent.parent&container_width=0&locale=en_US&login_text=&scope=public_profile,email,pages_messaging,pages_show_list,pages_manage_metadata&sdk=joey)

Bellow is the screen from Token Debuger:

https://prnt.sc/14o22pa

Issue:

I am trying to issue token for following scopes: public_profile,email,pages_messaging,pages_show_list,pages_manage_metadata. but token gets public_profile scope only.

P.s.
All was working fine yesterday(Didn't do any changes to my code), I have all the permissions on my FB-APP.

Comment: What happens when you remove the app completely in your profile’s settings, and then try to login again - do you get _asked_ for all those permissions?

Comment: Nope, it's just "Name and profile picture". i tried both removing app from my account settings and from FB-APP using DELETE {user-id}/permissions.

Comment: I’d try with the current version of the button code first of all, and see if that changes anything. `<fb:login-button>` is outdated, the current HTML5 version uses a div with a specific class and data attributes for the parameters. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button

Comment: @CBroe thanks for advise, same issue with HTML5 button. looks like url doesn't respect "scope=" part

Comment: And who says this specific URL is still supposed to be working …? When I test the current version of the button on the mentioned documentation page, it uses a different URL. So